# launchctl git: command not found

Tags: macos, git, command, launchd

Ok, so I am attempting to setup a auto commit on my github account using launchctl. To do this i created a sh file that preforms the git commands and a plist file that execuates the sh every 2 minutes, and the plist files fails. The sh runs fine when run outside of the plist

launchctl log is:

```
Aug  2 00:02:24 Caseys-iMac com.github.gitSync[9227]: /usr/bin/gitsync.sh: line 4: git: command not found
Aug  2 00:02:24 Caseys-iMac com.github.gitSync[9227]: /usr/bin/gitsync.sh: line 5: git: command not found
Aug  2 00:02:24 Caseys-iMac com.github.gitSync[9227]: /usr/bin/gitsync.sh: line 6: git: command not found
Aug  2 00:02:24 Caseys-iMac com.apple.launchd.peruser.501[123] (com.github.gitSync[9227]): Exited with code: 127
```

the plist file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple Computer//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN"

"http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">

<plist version="1.0">
  <dict>
    <key>Label</key>
    <string>com.github.GitSync</string>
    <key>Program</key>
    <string>/usr/bin/gitsync.sh</string>
    <key>ProgramArguments</key>
    <array>
    <string>gitsync.sh</string>
    </array>
    <key>RunAtLoad</key>
    <true />
    <key>StartInterval</key>
    <integer>120</integer>
  </dict>
</plist>
```

The sh file

```
#!/bin/bash
DATE=`date`
cd /Applications/Minecraft\ Server/
git pull origin master
git commit -a -m "Auto Sync - $DATE"
git push origin master
```

Please help

Answer (score 1):

You don't have git on the path. Add the path where you have the git exe to the path environment variable.

Answer (score 1):

The [man page of `launchd.plist`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man5/launchd.plist.5.html#//apple_ref/doc/man/5/launchd.plist) mentions:

```
UserName <string>
```

> This optional key specifies the user to run the job as. This key is only applicable when `launchd` is running as root.

So:

- your user might have `git` in his path (since you mention that "The `sh` runs fine when run outside of the `plist`")
- but if `launchd` is running as root, root might not have git in its path.

If possible, it would be best to specify in your `plist` file the user under which the job should be running.